# AWS Free tier exceeded, How to stop the services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently got this email from AWS budgets, saying I have exceeded the usage of AWS free tier. And when i check the Billing Dashboard -- > Free Tier , it displayed following table.

[image]

I have terminated all the instances and released all the AMIs . Still it shows the same status on my Billing dashboard.

How can I make sure that I am no more using any services that will cost me?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FQLGLNLXMAQxN1j?format=jpg&name=900x900

Comment: All EC2 instances are terminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can take up to around 24 hours to reflect changes on the billing dashboard.

In the meantime, I'd make sure there are no more EBS volumes or snapshots remaining as well. If you're worried that you may have missed any resources, go into cost explorer and drill down by daily spend. This should show anything still accruing costs.